# Angular2 auto select dropdown option if condition

Tags: html, angular

I have an template, where a service populates the values used in a select box. Like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="backings_select">Backing</label>
    <select class="form-control"
            required
            name="backings_select"
            (ngModelChange)="storeValueRedux($event, count)">
    <option *ngFor="let backing of backings" [ngValue]="backing.id">{{backing.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The above works fine. So I figured, if the array **backings** only has one  item, I might as well have angular auto select the one value that is available (for UI improvement)

So for a basic, hacky proof of concept I tried:

```
<div *ngIf="backings?.length == 1" class="form-group">
    <label for="backings_select">Backing Single</label>
    <select class="form-control"
            required
            name="backings_select"
            (ngModelChange)="storeValueRedux($event, count)">


    <option *ngFor="let backing of backings" [ngValue]="backing.id" selected="selected">{{backing.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div *ngIf="backings?.length > 1" class="form-group">
    <label for="backings_select">Backing Multiple</label>
    <select class="form-control"
            required
            name="backings_select"
            (ngModelChange)="storeValueRedux($event, count)">
    <option *ngFor="let backing of backings" [ngValue]="backing.id">{{backing.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now if **backings.length == 1**, the following html is rendered:

```
<option selected="selected" value="1: 1" ng-reflect-ng-value="1">nameValue</option>
```

And if **backings.length > 1** the following html is rendered:

```
<option value="0: 1" ng-reflect-ng-value="1">nameValue1</option>
<option value="1: 2" ng-reflect-ng-value="2">nameValue2</option>
```

Now in theory, the above code should work, however when length==1 the html select box is not auto selecting the value with selected="selected". Have I missed anything, or is there any reason why the select is not auto selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[selected]` instead of `selected`

```
<option *ngFor="let backing of backings" [ngValue]="backing.id" [selected]="backings.length === 1">{{backing.name}}</option>
```

without using ngIf and duplicating your code you can achieve the desired result like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="backings_select">Backing</label>
    <select class="form-control"
            required
            name="backings_select"
            (ngModelChange)="storeValueRedux($event, count)">
         <option *ngFor="let backing of backings" [ngValue]="backing.id" [selected]="backings.length === 1">{{backing.name}}</option>
{{backing.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But it introduces a new problem, if there is only one value, it auto selects  the value, but this does not invoke ngModelChange, is there anyway around this?

Comment: I think you should add a disabled option that must be auto selected, and force the user to select another option

Comment: With this application in particular, I want to trigger ngModelChange automatically if only one instance of the array exists, as even though the option is being auto selected, the Model is still changing, and should still fire the event (but it doesn't, even though the model has changed) Is there no way I can do this?

Comment: sorry I don't know